# mallocing same variable multiple times in c

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

Can I malloc the same variable multiple times in a loop, will it get a allocate it a new memory address?

```
int* var;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

Does this allocate a new space, this is not how I would actually use it, I would use in a situation where the address would be reassigned to a linked list so it could be freed and would not cause a memory address.

Comment: Yes, you get a new allocation each time. And leak the previous ones.

Comment: Yes, to avoid leakage, you must retain a pointer to the old value somewhere before reloading/reseating 'var'. as answered by @Unh0lys0da below,

Comment: You are not "mallocing a variable".  Your code allocates 5 distinct regions of memory, and you have lost the address of 4 of them.  The address of the 5th is held in the variable `var`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is fine as long as you do something with the variable before reassigning.
And with 'do something' I mean: make a copy of the pointer before reassigning it and call free on that copy later.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I malloc the same variable multiple times in a loop, will it get a allocate it a new memory address?

`malloc` allocates a block of *size* bytes of memory, returning a pointer to the beginning of the block. So, in this `for` loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

in every iteration, `malloc` is allocating a new block of memory and **returning a pointer to the beginning of the block which is getting assigned to `var` variable**. But you have mentioned in the question - "*address would be reassigned to a linked list..*" so, assuming you are keeping the allocated memory references somewhere.

This is as good as this:

```
int somevalue;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    somevalue = i+10; //Just assigning a value to variable
}
```

In every iteration, a new value is getting assigned to `somevalue` variable. After loop finishes, the variable `somevalue` will have the value assigned in the last iteration of the loop.

> Does this allocate a new space..

Yes, as long as `malloc` is successful.

---

Additional note:

Do not cast the `malloc` return. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

So, you should:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```